# How to prevent react router 5 to render DashboardLayout component below specific route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create a route that works as follows:

```
 <Route path='/home' exact component={Home}/>
{loggedin &&
<DashboardLayout>
<Route path='/settings' exact component={Settings} />
<Route path='/edit' exact component={AdMaker} />
</DashboardLayout>
}
```

If I am logged in, the DashboardLayout is rendering which I dont want if the route is /home. What should i do? [Please recommend methods other than switch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different way to do it, one of them is checking the `pathname`

```
let location = useLocation();

let checkIsHome = () => {
    return location.pathname?.includes('home')
}
 
<Route path='/home' exact component={Home}/>
{loggedin && !checkIsHome() &&
  <DashboardLayout>
    <Route path='/settings' exact component={Settings} />
    <Route path='/edit' exact component={AdMaker} />
  </DashboardLayout>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`useRouteMatch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) in the parent component to determine if the current route is the `"/home"` path and render the `DashboardLayout` wrapper component or a React `Fragment` wrapper.

Example:

```
const isHome = useRouteMatch("/home");

const LayoutWrapper = loggedIn && !isHome
  ? DashboardLayout
  : React.Fragment;

return (
  ...
  <LayoutWrapper>
    <Route path='/home' exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/settings' exact component={Settings} />
    <Route path='/edit' exact component={AdMaker} />
  </LayoutWrapper>
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-prevent-react-router-5-to-render-dashboardlayout-component-below-specific]

An alternative is to render a non-"/home" route that renders the `LayoutWrapper`. For this you can provide an array of paths you want to render with the `DashboardLayout`.

Example:

```
const LayoutWrapper = loggedIn ? DashboardLayout : React.Fragment;

return (
  ...
  <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
  <Route path={["/settings", "/edit"]}>
    <LayoutWrapper>
      <Route path="/settings" exact component={Settings} />
      <Route path="/edit" exact component={AdMaker} />
    </LayoutWrapper>
  </Route>
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-prevent-react-router-5-to-render-dashboardlayout-component-below-specific (forked)]

OFC, using the `Switch` component would simplify this all a bit. It's a bit unclear why you *wouldn't* want to use it. The reason the `Switch` component is useful and helps is that it *exclusively* matches and renders routes and you won't need to pepper the `exact` prop over each and every one of the routes.

Example:

```
const LayoutWrapper = loggedIn ? DashboardLayout : React.Fragment;

return (
  ...
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route>
      <LayoutWrapper>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/edit" component={AdMaker} />
        </Switch>
      </LayoutWrapper>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
  ...
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-prevent-react-router-5-to-render-dashboardlayout-component-below-specific (forked)]